# Tex install gone wrong on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.04, latex, dependencies

My computer crashed halfway through apt-get installing tex-common. When I tried again after rebooting I got various error messages relating to missing configuration entries eg

```
 Essential entry missing in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf                                                                                                         │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                                   │ 
 │ An essential entry is missing in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf:                                                                                                  │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                                   │ 
 │ No setting of TEXFONTMAPS.                                                                                                                                        │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                                   │ 
 │ TeX will not work until the configuration files are fixed. The version of /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf that is provided by the package should be available as   │ 
 │ /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf.ucf-dist.                                                                                                                          │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                                   │ 
 │ The configuration process has been aborted.
```

And similar ones for TEXMFMAIN, TEXMFDIST and TEXMF in files
/etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf
and
/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf

It says the files should be available as blah.cnf.ucf-dist, but all I can find are blah.cnf.ucf-old.

Trying to purge/reinstall/remove/anything using apt-get fails with the same error messages, and so does dpkg -a --configure (which apt-get points me to sometimes).

I feel like I'm in a pickle. Does anyone know a quick command to clean up the mess to reinstall, or where I can find the cnf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Synaptic to completely remove any packages related to tex seems to have worked, I've successfully installed Texmaker, anyway.